# Prevent excel from reformatting values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of data. I marked the column as "Text". The data resembles the following:

```
5,5
6,5
5,5
8,5
4,5
...
```

With batch replace operation, I want to convert commas to dots. However, Excel converts the entry either to date (5. maj) or, if enforce Text in replace dialogue, to some obscure number such as `42130`. See the screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

How to tell Excel not to try to be a wise guy and just do what I tell it.

Thanks

Comment: The reason for the "obscure number" is simple. You seem to be using Excel on a machine having its decimal separator set to "comma" and also the separator in dates to "dot" (Germany for example). Thus Excel assumes your "four and a half" has to be written "4 comma 5". As soon as you turn it to "4 dot 5", it thinks you are talking about the 4th of May. The (mostly hidden) date representation (you exposed by your formatting) in Excel is the number you are getting. It is numbering days since the 1st of January 1900 (which is "1") btw. ;-)

Comment: Copy the column to to notepad++ and do the substitution there! Excel will always try to be a wise guy... :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the cells have already been formatted as *Text*, just select the cells you wish to convert and run this small macro:

```
Sub NoComma()
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, ",") > 0 Then
            v = Replace(v, ",", ".")
            r.Value = v
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

This macro will not make frivolous or gratuitous changes to the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Put a single quote as the first character of the value.

```
'5,5
'6,5
'5,5
'8,5
'4,5
'...
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting single quotes before values is probably the solution for you, as answered by Steven.
I don't know whether you can do this in batch replacer, I use regex add-in and its quite easy to do there:
Search for: `"([0-9]*),([0-9]*)"`.
Replace to: `"'\1.\2"`